# How to remove unnecessary indexes in EF Code First?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have `BaseExtendedEntity` with about 250 classes that inherit from it and it has some relations with `User` Entity and so it has index for all of them but it's unnecessary and it reduces the database performance.

Is it possible to configure EF to drop these indexes using fluent API or data annotations?

Comment: Just remove them from the Migration?

Comment: If you're shooting for that kind of performance, EF might not be the right tool. Take a look at dapper.

Comment: @ErikEJ I was looking for a more simple way to do that instead of writing 750 lines of migration

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks, I'll take a look at it